# Weird Word Character breaks AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, unicode

I seem to be having a probelm whenever I try and send something by AJAX that has the Word '-' (hyphen) character in it. It seems to turn he whole string into 'null' in PHP when I convert to JSON.

Has anyone else seen/solved this?

Comment: Will post code this eve - not sure it'll help; seemd to just be generic to an AJAX/JSON call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you using? json_decode?  Try seeing what you get out of json_last_error

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

The json decode example function has in it, a dash, so its probably not an issue.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Check the section on there that says 'common errors'.

Answer (score 4):

the "Word hyphen" you're talking about is probably an em-dash. This is not a standard ascii character, which means that your issue is likely to be around character encoding.

Either encode all the extended characters in your string as HTML entities using the PHP [htmlentities()](http://uk.php.net/htmlentities) function, or else ensure that all your content is served as UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right; whenever you type a hyphen in word it automatically replaces it with em-dash - it looks like a 'long hyphen'

Comment: @Hogsmill - It also does similar things to quotation marks and other punctuation.